# append and select only appended element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a keyup function to an appended elements, but all elements with the same Class are receiving the event.

```
this.ul.append('<li><div class="suggest_tag addSectionTag"><span class="LabelInput"><input type="text" class=""><span class="LabelInput_Label">Adiciona um título...</span></span></div></li>').hide()
```

this is my simples code. This will hide all LI elements inside the this.ul = $('#testing ul') selector. I just want it to hide the appended element.

Any clue?

Comment: You re right, I am trying to understand how this work yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you're using jquery:

```
this.ul.append('<li><div class="suggest_tag addSectionTag"><span class="LabelInput"><input type="text" class=""><span class="LabelInput_Label">Adiciona um título...</span></span></div></li>');
this.ul.find('li:last').hide();
```

Comment: theres no way to do it directly after the append?

Comment: Yes, seems that you can use it in one row like `this.ul.append('...').find('li:last').hide();`